# how to Instantiate class object in better way

Tags: c#, constructor, instantiation

I have `Student` class with following few properties.

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string RollNumber{get;set;}
    public string StudentType{get;set;}
    public string Class{get;set;}
}
```

I am instantiating an object of Student class as following in my code.

```
public void Update(Student student)
{
    Student orignal = new Student { 
        Id = student.Id, 
        RollNumber = student.RollNumber, 
        StudentType = student.StudentType, 
        Class = student.Class
    };
}
```

The above works fine but i feel that there must be a better way to do this because what if i have `100 properties in Student class` than putting all them in `Student student = new Student {.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,............. upto 100}` is bad way.

Can i do it in better way?

Comment: Are you really asking how to *copy*?

Comment: why dont you just copy the object like Student original = student;

Comment: @ jonrsharpe, no i am asking good way to instantiate if any.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you haven't come across a constructor before learning this syntax

Comment: If you have 100 properties on a class you are most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

1. Don't put 100 properties in the class :) It usually indicates bad design and another class trying to break free.
2. If you do have a considerable number of attributes that are always necessary, try the builder pattern instead. That lets you have some generic half-ready objects saved for later.

Alternatively, maybe you have a lot of default values which you don't have to specify every single time you construct a new object?

Comment: can i do it having constructor in my class?

Answer (score 1):

Well, having a class with 100 properties is bad design anyway... You can add a constructor, to at least save you the effort of writing each property name on every instance.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about **builder pattern**. This is a very nice tool to initialize classes, especially when not all fields must be defined at the construction time. There are serveral implementations, I think however that [this one](http://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/) would be the most benefitial for your case.